# converting complex number into polar coordinates

Tags: python-3.x

I got this code below from a blog.

```
import cmath
print(*cmath.polar(complex(input())), sep='\n')
```

My question is, why is '`*`' asterisk used in the `print` function?
What is the function of '`*`' ?

Comment: Try taking it out and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert and correct me if I made a mistake,but as far as I know, using * in print will unpack the iterable.

For example,

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4]  #list
y=(0,1,2,3)    #tuple
print(*x)
print(x)
print(*y)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
[0,1,2,3,4]
0,1,2,3
(0,1,2,3)
```

In the line -

```
print(*cmath.polar(complex(input())), sep='\n')
```

cmath.polar(complex(input())) returns a tuple with polar coordinates.

'*' is used to unpack the tuple and return only elements.